# Navigating IE object via VBA code

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have a VBA code which allows me to read/place string in HTML objects (like input boxes).
This is the example of code:

```
Sub ReadCheck() 

Dim objlement As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim isNothing As Boolean

'
Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
i = shellWins.Count

'On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To i - 1
    If shellWins.Item(i).Parent = "Internet Explorer" Then
        If shellWins.Item(i).Document.URL = "https://intservices.mybebpage" Then
            Set ie = shellWins.Item(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0


isNothing = ie Is Nothing
Debug.Print Format(Now, "HH:MM:SS") & " IE is nothing: " & isNothing
If isNothing Then Exit Sub



'combo box
Set objlement = ie.Document.getelementsbyname("txtboxx")
objlement (0).Value = "Some text to place"


End Sub
```

Due to my testing, this code works fine with 99% of cases, but sometimes it returns error 91 (*Object variable or With block variable not set*), in the last line.

I'm pretty sure, that I can get correct object for objelement, but it looks like there were no *.Value* property for it.
This is wierd, becouse I know that this code works.
In my opinion the most possible reason for this is that I should use some different properties than .Value for this.
Do you have any comments for this?

Comment: When the error is occur, do you have check your ie.document contains value or not? Sometimes html document contains no value. Perhaps you should add something to check to make sure your ie.document contains value.

Comment: Yes, ie.document has value, but now I've noticed interesting thing: when I test if **objelement(0) is nothing**, macro returnes true, on the other hand, when I test if **objelement is nothing** - it returns false.
Unfortunatelly property .value does not work for objelement either.